# AngularJS consecutive $http calls not returning correct data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below AngularJS controller and service modules. Basically what I wanted to do is to refresh `custController.allCustomers` after creating a new customer so that the new customer is showing up on the UI.

However, whenever I call `custController.createCustomer`, the data in `allCustomers` never has the new customer. I suspect there is something wrong in the way I use promise. Could you please help?

controlers.js

```
angular.module('CustomerModule')
.controller('CustomerController', function ($log, CustomerService) {
    console.log("CustomerController initializing");
    var custController = this;
    custController.newCustomer = {};

    custController.refresh = function () {
        CustomerService.getAllCustomers().success(function (response) {
            custController.allCustomers = response;
        });
        custController.newCustomer = {};
    };

    custController.createCustomer = function (customer) {
        CustomerService.createCustomer(customer).success(function (response) {
            custController.refresh();
        });
    };

    custController.refresh();
});
```

The Service module (services.js)

```
angular.module('CustomerModule')
.service('CustomerService', function ($http) {
    var service = this;

    service.getAllCustomers = function () {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/customers");
    };

    service.createCustomer = function (customer) {
        console.log("Creating customer ", customer);
        return $http.post("http://localhost:8080/customers", customer);
    };
});
```

Add the rest code in case they help:
app.js

```
var app = angular.module('CustomerModule', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '../dashboard.html',
            controller: 'CustomerController',
            controllerAs: 'custController'
        })
        .when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: '../dashboard.html',
            controller: 'CustomerController',
            controllerAs: 'custController'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='CustomerModule'>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/dashboard">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div ng-view></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app/services.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

dashboard.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header"><h2>All Customers</h2></div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Contact</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Action</td>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat='customer in ::custController.allCustomers'>
            <td>{{::customer.name}}</td>
            <td>{{::customer.contact}}</td>
            <td>{{::customer.address}}</td>
            <td>{{::customer.email}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href='#/updateCustomer/{{customer.customerID}}'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                <a ng-click='custController.deleteCustomer(customer)'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header"><h2>Create a Customer</h2></div>

    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>

            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name"
                       ng-model="custController.newCustomer.name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputContact">Contact</label>

            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputContact" placeholder="Contact"
                       ng-model="custController.newCustomer.contact"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputAddress">Address</label>

            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Address"
                       ng-model="custController.newCustomer.address"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>

            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email"
                       ng-model="custController.newCustomer.email"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="custController.createCustomer(custController.newCustomer)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Not clear what you wanted to do with the property `custController.newCustomer`. Is it bound to the template? It's always an empty object.

Comment: are you sure that the new customer is actually saved on the server? otherwise your function would be returning the right data, but you wouldn't see the new customer because it isn't on the db.

Comment: @DenisBokor Yes, the new customer is always saved. It is populated into allCustomers when I refresh the page. but it is supposed to be populated automatically without me refreshing the page - or the function that I wanted to achieve.

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos new customer is the model used in a form to create the customer, it's data is cleared after it is saved into server so the form resets.

Comment: @BOND but why are you passing customer to createCustomer? couldn't you just call  CustomerService.createCustomer(newCustomer)> ? this dosn't solve your problem though.

Comment: @DenisBokor The customer is passed from the html template. Basically ng-click=customerContoller.create(newCustomer). I can also use new customer directly. But as you said, this is not the problem I'm facing :(

Comment: can you post a js fiddle?

Comment: You have a typo this should be: ng-click="customerContoller.createCustomer(newCustomer)"

Comment: @DenisBokor not sure how to use js fiddle, but pasted all the source code.

Comment: Maybe it's because you're using the bind-once sintax? So after the rows are rendered angular will unbind custController.allCustomers and the rows won't change, at least that's what I've understood of bind-once. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @DenisBokor I think that is one way bind. Only changes in the model will be binded to the view, changes in the view will not be binded to the model. I used it because that is a read only view to override the default two way binding.

Comment: @BOND there is a difference between "one way" binding and "one time" binding. You are using the bind once functionality, it's not going to update the value again.

Comment: @DenisBokor thanks Denis. That's exactly the problem. I can't accept a comment but voted up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the "one time" binding expressions in your HTML. Per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding):

> An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value (see value stabilization algorithm below).

This is not "one way" binding where the value only updates in one direction. This is is going to stop updating the view after the value has "stablized" (is not undefined).